# Assign Multiple Values To Multiple Data Structures

Tags: javascript, typescript, data-structures

I was wondering what would be the best / efficient way to assign multiple values to 5 different instances of the same data structure (all the data structures are the same).

My Data Structure:

```
export class WeatherData {
    date: string;
    city: string;
    country: string;
    temperature: number;
    minTemperature: number;
    maxTemperature: number;
    weather: any;
    weatherIcon: any;
}
```

So for example, my values for minTemperature are currently in a number array with length 5 that contains the minimum temperature for each day. In other words, each instance of the data structure represents one day.

Is there a way for me to assign the ith element of that array to the minTemperature of the ith data structure? This will have to be done for the other fields of the data structure as well (date, city, country, ...)

Comment: This looks like typescript to me. If it is please edit your post to say so.

Comment: Changed it. Figured there wouldn't be any difference if it was TypeScript or JavaScript.

Comment: Are you wanting  a `new WeatherData()` for each of those 5 items?

Comment: Yes, each one will have different values for each of those fields according to the values in my arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you two answers as intuition tells me you're probably better suited with an interface in this case:

**With the given class:**

```js
export class WeatherData {
    date: string;
    city: string;
    country: string;
    temperature: number;
    minTemperature: number;
    maxTemperature: number;
    weather: any;
    weatherIcon: any;
    // set up a constructor:
    constructor(props?: Partial<WeatherData>) {
      // take an optional object containing properties of weather data and assign it
      Object.assign(this, props);
    }
}

// Setup for clarity sake
const temperatures[] = //....
const countries[] = //....
// more arrays as given...

let weatherDataObjects: WeatherData[] = [];
// Assuming these arrays are all the same length:
for (let i = 0; i < temperatures.length; i++) {
  weatherDataObjects.push(new WeatherData({
    temperature: temperatures[i],
    country: countries[i],
    // ... assign the rest
  }));
}
```

However, as noted earlier, if you don't plan on having any member methods to your WeatherData class an interface will probably suit you better - essentially a constrained, type-checked object.
**With an interface:**

```js
interface WeatherData {
    date: string;
    city: string;
    country: string;
    temperature: number;
    minTemperature: number;
    maxTemperature: number;
    weather: any;
    weatherIcon: any;
}

// Setup for clarity sake
const temperatures[] = //....
const countries[] = //....
// more arrays as given...

let weatherDataObjects: WeatherData[] = [];
// Assuming these arrays are all the same length:
for (let i = 0; i < temperatures.length; i++) {
  weatherDataObjects.push({
    temperature: temperatures[i],
    country: countries[i],
    // ... assign the rest
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm not a typescript guru but you don't appear to be using the actual interface